# Changing the text when you click on the buttons with typewriter effect

Tags: javascript

I want a certain text to be displayed to me depending on the button pressed. In the array I have set the text that needs to be assigned to the buttons. I know that can do this by passing a parameter (a++) to the type Text function when you click on the button, but for some reason it doesn't work. And it gives the error "Assignment to constant variable" If I don't add this parameter, then it outputs only the first word in the array to all buttons

```js
const a = [];
a[0] = "На концерты";
a[1] = "На мероприятия";
a[2] = "На фестиваль";
a[3] = "На шоу";
a[4] = "На онлайн-событие";
const typewriter = document.querySelector('.typewriter')
// печать
function typeText() {
  let line = 0; // номер строки
  let count = 0; // счетчик позиции
  let out = ''; // то что мы делаем
  function typeLine() {
    // рисует строки
    let timeout = setInterval(function() {
      out += a[0][line][count];
      typewriter.innerHTML = out;
      count++;
      if (count >= a[0][line].length) {
        count = 0;
        line++;

      }
      if (line == a[0].length) {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        return true;
      }
    }, 70);
  }
  typeLine();
}
typeText();
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#buttonsId')
Array.from(buttons).map((item, index) => item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  typeText(a++)
}))
```

```html
<div class="header_text">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header_text__block">
      <h1>Сервис <br> продажи билетов</h1>
      <p class="typewriter"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="header__button">
      <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="0"><a href="#">Конференция</a></button>
      <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="1"><a href="#">Выставка</a></button>
      <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="2"><a href="#">Шоу</a></button>
      <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="3"><a href="#">Онлайн</a></button>
      <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="4"><a href="#">Театр</a></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you even trying with `a++`? `a` is an array, `++` is for numbers, not for arrays

Answer (score 0):

Const variables can't be changed. The variable `a` is declared as `const`. Declare your variable with `let` instead of `const`.

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') @siddhu-learn-javascript

Comment: Another error? I'll check

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = [];
a[0] = "На концерты";
a[1] = "На мероприятия";
a[2] = "На фестиваль";
a[3] = "На шоу";
a[4] = "На онлайн-событие";
const typewriter = document.querySelector('.typewriter')
// печать
function typeText(index = 0) {
  let line = 0; // номер строки
  let count = 0; // счетчик позиции
  let out = ''; // то что мы делаем
  function typeLine() {
    // рисует строки
    let timeout = setInterval(function() {
      out += a[index][line][count];
      typewriter.innerHTML = out;
      count++;
      if (count >= a[index][line].length) {
        count = 0;
        line++;

      }
      if (line == a[index].length) {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        return true;
      }
    }, 70);
  }
  typeLine();
}
typeText();
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#buttonsId')
console.log(buttons)
Array.from(buttons).map((item, index) => item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  typeText(index)
}))
```

```html
<div class="header_text">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header_text__block">
      <h1>Сервис <br> продажи билетов</h1>
      <p class="typewriter"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="header__button">
      <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="0"><a href="#">Конференция</a></button>
      <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="1"><a href="#">Выставка</a></button>
      <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="2"><a href="#">Шоу</a></button>
      <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="3"><a href="#">Онлайн</a></button>
      <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="4"><a href="#">Театр</a></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try to passing the index to `typeText` function, it is works for me. Noted that index param has a default value 0.